# Using two selection types in altair: disable old selection

Tags: python, visualization, altair

Is there a way to have two selection types in altair (i.e., a dropdown and a direct selection of a point in a scatterplot), but only have one active at a time?

As a minimal example of what I am looking for,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5], 'age':[20,20,19,16,26], 'IQ':[100,79,50,103,99]})

selection_MOUSE = alt.selection_multi(fields=['ID'])
dropdownIDs = alt.binding_select(options=[1,2,3,4,5], name="Selector: ")
selection_DROPDOWN = alt.selection_single(fields=['ID'], bind=dropdownIDs)

c = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(
    filled=True
    ).encode(
        x=alt.X('age:Q'),
        y=alt.Y('IQ:Q'),
        opacity=alt.condition(selection_MOUSE | selection_DROPDOWN, alt.value(1), alt.value(.2)),
        tooltip=['ID']
    ).add_selection(selection_MOUSE, selection_DROPDOWN).interactive()

c.display()
```

It's a bit hard to see, but this is the result of one point being *clicked* and then another point being *chosen via the dropdown*.

[image: It's a bit hard to see, but this is the result of one point being clicked and then another point being chosen via the dropdown]

As the opacity is dependent on the selection, when a point on the graph is clicked, it remains dark and the rest go gray. When a choice is then chosen from the dropdown, the corresponding point on the graph becomes dark *but the old chosen point is still dark*.

I was wondering if there is any way to have two types of selection, but have each new selection *overrride* the old selection. So the desired result would be that the latest chosen point (whether it is via a click or a dropdown selection) will be the only darkened point on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is an XOR operation. Per altair's documentation (https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#composing-multiple-selections) they only provide the AND, OR, and NOT operations so you'll have to create your own XOR as shown:

`(selection_MOUSE & ~selection_DROPDOWN) | (~selection_MOUSE & selection_DROPDOWN)`